# Ordenar array vindo primeiro o objeto

Tags: javascript, objetos

Tenho um objeto que retorna array e objeto ao mesmo tempo
Exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu consegui recuperar o objeto chamando direto

```
var obj = { name: obj.name, month: obj.month, year: obj.year }
```

Tem como eu ordenar esse array para trazer primeiro o objeto antes do array ?

Exemplo :

```
objeto,
  [0] objeto,
  [1] objeto,
  [2] objeto
```

Perceba que na imagem ele recupera o objeto por ultimo

Comment: A sua pergunta parece muito vasta [Como Perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) tente [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/359257/edit) a sua pergunta, colocar o código pode ajudar a encontrar o problema

Comment: Esse objeto está estranho... o que dá `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));`?

Comment: Isso parece um array em que você também criou chaves como o `name` e `year` e por isso acaba por complicar. Como é construida essa informação ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível fazer o que você pede. Em um objeto, **todas as propriedades** que tem **chave** numérica são colocadas para cima e sorteadas automaticamente, mesmo que você crie o objeto originalmente com elas "em baixo":

```js
const myObject = {
  name: "Geral",
  age: null,
  // Note que as propriedades com chave numérica estão no final:
  0: {
    name: "Foo"
  },
  1: {
    name: "Bar"
  }
}

// Note agora, no log do console, que as propriedades com chave
// numéricas estarão no início do objeto.
console.log(myObject)
```

### O que você pode fazer?

Neste caso, você pode criar uma função que transforma esse objeto em um `array` de `array`s chave-valor. Algo assim:

```js
function sortObjectItems(o) {
  const normalKeys = []
  const numericKeys = []

  for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(o)) {
    // Caso a chave da propriedade da iteração atual for um valor numérico:
    if (/^\d+$/.test(key)) {
      numericKeys.push([parseInt(key, 10), val])
    // Caso a chave da propriedade da iteração atual não for um valor numérico:
    } else {
      normalKeys.push([key, val])
    }
  }

  // Concatenamos os dois arrays criados e retornamos eles:
  return [...normalKeys, ...numericKeys]
}

const sortedArray = sortObjectItems({
  0: { name: 'Foo', age: 1 },
  1: { name: 'Bar', age: 2 },
  name: 'Baz',
  age: 3
})

console.log(sortedArray)
```

No exemplo acima, você sempre receberá algo como:

```
[[key, value], [key, value] ...]
```

Dado o comportamento do objeto no JavaScript, penso que esta seja a melhor solução para o seu problema.

### Referência:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33351816/how-to-prevent-automatic-sort-of-object-numeric-property